# Secure Authentication and Authorization in core Java Application

Tags: java, swing, authentication, authorization, jaas

I asked this question two days before and I got no answer, thats why I am posting this question again. Please try to help,

I am developing a core java application which works with file system most. But I am stuck with one question. How to provide secure Authentication and Authorization to my application. The basic thing comes in my mind is either Singleton or Factory Pattern. I have heard about two more API's which is

JAAS - Java Authentication and Authorization Service
JCA - Java Cryptography Architecture

But I am not aware of these two API's and also that whether they support to core Java or not. So I have some final question which is,

Q1. Do I need to implement JAAS/JCA to make Authentication and Authorization secure?
Q2. OR any design pattern can solve my this Authentication and Authorization issue?
Q3. OR there can any other simpler way to do this?

Some Information related to my project:-
It is a bank project which should perform file reconciliation(i.e. checking of two different files, so that they contain proper report or not).
UI - Swing
Business logic - core java
DB - Oracle

If anyone finds any issue in this question please try to correct.

Comment: I would recommend using the Programmers StackExchange community. It is meant to deal with conceptual and implementation questions

Comment: In any case yuo may use JAAS for authentication and authorization and criptografy for file system (if you need it); and I'ld suggest to you to give a look to spring security http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.6.RELEASE/reference/technical-overview.html I hope it helps, Angelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I am not aware of these two API's and also that whether they support to core Java or not.

1. There is lots of information on the Web on these APIs.  JAAS is more directly relevant to your problem.
2. JCA and JAAS APIs are part of Java SE class library.

> So I have some final question which is,
>
> Q1. Do I need to implement JAAS/JCA to make Authentication and Authorization secure?

Not necessarily.  There are lots of other ways to implement authentication and authorization that do not involve JAAS or (directly) JCA.

> Q2. OR any design pattern can solve my this Authentication and Authorization issue?

Erm ... no.

> Q3. OR there can any other simpler way to do this?

There are lots of alternatives, especially if you are talking about securing a web-based service.  Whether they are simpler depends on what your actual requirements are.